# Using HttpClient inside ASP.NET MVC Action to call SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I can't seem to send a request to report server using **HttpClient** as the result is always 
***401 (Unauthorized)***.

The action is

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> SSRSTest()
            {

                //set credentials
                using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { 
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password"),
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false
                })

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    //get *.pdf from report server
                    var response = await httpClient                      .GetStreamAsync("http://someip/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?TheRemainingPartOfURL");


                    var contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition
                    {
                        FileName = "SomeReport.pdf",
                        Inline = false
                    };

                    //set content disposition
                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());

                    //return the file
                    return File(response, "application/pdf");
                }
            }
```

**Additional:**

[Pass a Report Parameter Within a URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx)

[Export a Report Using URL Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154040.aspx)

[Export Formats](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239307.aspx#ExportFormats)

[Generate Data Feeds from a Report](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519563.aspx)

Comment: Do the user have access to reporting services?

Comment: @scheien Yes, when i paste the URL in the browser address bar or if i use the link as a href it works.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a domain name as third parameter of your NetworkCredential constructor ?

Comment: @jbl It has several overloads so i think this isn't an issue.

Comment: I know ;-) The point is that maybe you should put something in this parameter (like the domain domain name, or machine name)

Comment: @jbl Doesn't work with the domain parameter.

Comment: Would it be just as easy and give you more control using the ReportExecutionService and the Render method after including the service reference in your project?

Comment: @lrb Thanks for the suggestion but i don't want to use ReportExecutionService. I just want to make a request to the report passing the params in the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used Fiddler to see what is going on when i login using browser

[image]

the **Auth** tab is

```
WWW-Authenticate Header is present: Negotiate    
WWW-Authenticate Header is present: NTLM
```

so even though I was told that the authentication is Basic i needed to use the following

```
 CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
            credentialCache.Add(new Uri("http://youruri"),"NTLM",new NetworkCredential(username, password));

            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Credentials = credentialCache
            })
```

The rest of the code for **HttpClient** is the same.

**Additional:**

[Authentication with the Report Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249.aspx)

[Selecting a Credential Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733836.aspx)

[Understanding SQL Server Reporting Services Authentication](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-reporting-services/understanding-sql-server-reporting-services-authentication)

[Configure Basic Authentication on the Report Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309.aspx)